# raise exception_from_status(DatabaseError, fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError: (' SQLCODE: -104\n- Dynamic SQL Error\n- SQL error code = -104\n- Token unknown

Tags: python, sql, firebird

Делаю запрос базе для получении данных из 2 таблиц

```
connect = fdb.connect(dsn='C:\c.gdb', user='sysdba', password='master')
cur = connect.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT BOOK1.R001F, CAR_A103.R1024"
        "FROM BOOK1 LEFT OUTER JOIN CARD_A103"
        "ON BOOK1.R001F = CAR_A103.R1024")
result= cur.fetchall()
print(result)
```

выдаёт ошибку

> raise exception_from_status(DatabaseError, self._isc_status,
> fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError: ('Error while preparing SQL statement:\n- SQLCODE: -104\n- Dynamic SQL Error\n- SQL error code = -104\n- Token unknown - line 1, column 56\n- LEFT', -104, 335544569)

Comment: у вас многострочный запрос как-то странно оформлен. не уверен, что так допустимо.  попробуйте использовать docstring. как, например, здесь: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2004-November/033477.html.

Comment: Нет возможности проверить, но что-то мне подсказывает, что при таком переносе строк в запросе, в результате эти строки конкатенируются, а не разделяются переносом. Таким образом, у вас конец предыдущей строки «прилипнет» к началу следующей. Попробуйте в конце первой и второй строки поставить пробелы (ну, или в начале второй и третьей - без разницы)

Comment: @strawdog да это помогло поставвь те в ответ, но теперь выдаёт ошибку raise exception_from_status(DatabaseError, self._isc_status, "Cursor.fetchone:")
fdb.fbcore.DatabaseError: ('Cursor.fetchone:\n- SQLCODE: -413\n- conversion error from string "Пин"', -413, 335544334) преобразования из строки это что может значить?

Comment: Какой тип данных у BOOK1.R001F и CAR_A103.R1024?

Comment: @Akina varchar и date

Comment: Значит, приводи их к одному типу явным CAST одного из операндов. У Firebird неявное приведение типа не в чести...